# rotate image in angularjs before upload

Tags: angularjs, image

I use ng-file-upload and ng-img-crop in my angularjs application. I want to be able to change the image orientation before crop. How can I do that?

**CSS:**

```
.cropArea {
    background: #E4E4E4;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="upload-section">
    <label class="upload-image" ngf-select ng-model="picFile"></label>
</div>
<div class="cropArea">
    <img-crop image="picFile  | ngfDataUrl" area-type="rectangle" aspect-ratio="1.5" result-image="croppedDataUrl" result-image-size="'max'" ng-init="croppedDataUrl=''"></img-crop>
</div>
```